# Access Telegram-CLI using php

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, telegram, fedora-23

I want to access the [Telegram-CLI](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) using PHP.

I'm compiled Telegram-CLI and loged in to my account, and its works like a charm. 
 
I installed LAMP ([in Linux], Apache, MySQL, PHP) and i tested them works. 
 
I even installed these [following] PHP packages one-by-one using "Composer" and tested the examples but i couldnt make them run...

Also it seems their forum are abandoned to get my questions answer.

- [php-client for telegram-cli](https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client)
- [A wrapper for Telegram-CLI](https://github.com/jlaso/telegram-cli-wrapper)
- [PHP Wrapper and Drupal module using Telegram CLI](https://github.com/josereyero/telegram)

Could somebody tell me how to make one of them work in simple way.

All steps of building Telegram-cli, loging in for first time and run it as deamon has beed completed.

For Example:

[This project](https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client) has been installed on php project root dir using "Composer".

Example.php file has been moved to web server root directory.
But also unning it cause a `500 Internal server error`.

The error line is:

```
$telegram = new \Zyberspace\Telegram\Cli\Client('unix:///tmp/tg.sck');
```

**notices:**
The file has been checked and is already there.

And the telegram-cli is running as a daemon on root user.

I added a `telegramd` group and `telegramd` user assigned to that group.

I detacted that php commands running under `apache` user account.

I changed the `apache` user group to `telegramd`.

But again nothing...

So, Please help me

**Edit:**

I changed the `httpd.conf` user and group parameters to run at the same (telegramd) account

```
User telegramd
Group telegramd
```

And i have restarted the apache and checked the username by

```
exec('whoami');
```

The Apache is running under "telegramd" user account.

But nothing again..

**Edit 2:**

error_log file:

[Wed Feb 10 11:02:04.251133 2016] [:error] [pid 1172] [client 10.0.1.24:49168] PHP Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to unix:///tmp/tg.sck (No such file or directory) in /var/www/html/vendor/zyberspace/telegram-cli-client/lib/Zyberspace/Telegram/Cli/RawClient.php on line 48
[Wed Feb 10 11:02:04.251332 2016] [:error] [pid 1172] [client 10.0.1.24:49168] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zyberspace\Telegram\Cli\ClientException' with message 'Could not connect to socket "unix:///tmp/tg.sck"' in /var/www/html/vendor/zyberspace/telegram-cli-client/lib/Zyberspace/Telegram/Cli/RawClient.php:51\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/example.php(10): Zyberspace\Telegram\Cli\RawClient->__construct('unix:///tmp/tg....')\n#1 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/zyberspace/telegram-cli-client/lib/Zyberspace/Telegram/Cli/RawClient.php on line 51

Comment: Oh god Somebody help me.

Comment: This is my first time in Linux. Don't disappoint me.

Comment: `chown :telegram /tmp/tg.sck`
`chmod g+rwx /tmp/tg.sck`

https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client#setup-telegram-cli

Comment: I've tried that in the past but nothing

Comment: I even tried that with -P xxxx (Port) argument then tried to connect with PHP 127.0.0.1:xxxx and nothing again. I'm surprised because i can access to that ip:port using telnet in linux.!!!!
Is that a miss config in PHP?

Comment: I even cant to telnet that port from other machine (my host windows)?
But i could telnet to port 80 and get response.
I have disabled all firewalls.

Whats wrong?

Comment: What about php-fpm? `PrivateTmp=true` in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service`. Need to be `false`.

Comment: > Is that a miss config in PHP?
Web server listen IP address on port, or all available IPs on the port. For example, if your web server configured to listen `80` port on `127.0.0.1` IP (`127.0.0.1:80`) — that port is unavailable for external requests. Use your external IP or no/all IP (such as `listen :80`).